# Check if I am running from a Pycharm console

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to do a clear screen on the console.
I got from os.name the operating system and giving the correct (CLS/CLEAR) command for console.
But if the code runs on Pycharm terminal it draws a small box instead.
If I can identify the terminal by code I could print('\n'*80) instead.
How can identify I am running from Pycharm terminal?

Comment: @Tomerikoo - I looked at that answer.  Did I miss where it answers this question...where it explains how to tell if you're running in PyCharm?  It seems that that question just assumes that's where your code is running.

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo , that does suggest other methods to clear the screen. Still needs local configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running in PyCharm, the `PYCHARM_HOSTED` environment variable will be set.  Here's a function that will tell you:

```
import os

def is_pycharm():
    return os.getenv("PYCHARM_HOSTED") != None

print("YES" if is_pycharm() else "NO")
```